# Get Object from KO.Observable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Sorry for the newbie question, I'm working with `KnockoutJS` and I am trying to get the base64String value from an observable and store it inside another observable before sending it off.

Why do I need to do that?
Well for some reason when the base64String is passed it has multiple layers to the object which get sent over as NULL.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

```
var CreateSalesVM = {
    UserId: ko.observable(),
    Name: ko.observable(),
    Phone: ko.observable(),
    Email: ko.observable(),
    Item: ko.observable(),
    Description: ko.observable()
```

This piece is what I am having the issue with

```
IMAGETWO: ko.observable({
    base64StringArray: ko.observableArray()
}),
IMAGE: ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return IMAGETWO().base64StringArray();
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
}),
```

/**************\

```
btnCreateSales: function () {
    //  IMAGE = this.IMAGETWO().base64StringArray();
    console.log("Image text ", this.IMAGE());

    //console.log("Host usrl ", urlHostPath);
    //console.log("Ko is ", ko.toJSON(this));
    $.ajax({
        url: urlPath,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ko.toJSON(this),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            //console.log("This was a success");
           // window.location.href = urlPath + '/';
            alert(ko.toJSON(this));
           // console.log("Ko is ", ko.toJSON(this));
        },
        error: function (err) {

            //console.log("Ko is ", ko.toJSON(this));
            if (err.responseText == "success")
            {
                //console.log("This was an erro success", urlPath);

               // window.location.href = urlPath + '';
            }
            else {
                alert(err.responseText);
               // console.log("This was an error ", urlHostPath );
            }
        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    });
}

};

 ko.applyBindings(CreateSalesVM);
```

Comment: What is the problem with your existing code?

Comment: Sorry, Throws an error - CreateVM.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: IMAGETWO is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMAGETWO` is a method of your VM object. You must specify the object while calling a function, otherwise it will look in a global scope for it. So, you may use either:

```
IMAGE: ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return this.IMAGETWO().base64StringArray();
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
}, CreateSalesVM)
```

or

```
IMAGE: ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return CreateSalesVM.IMAGETWO().base64StringArray();
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
})
```

Comment: @AdamWolski ah, right, I thought this was all in the same code block. My mistake then

Answer (score 0):

This fails because you didn't specify on which object to call `IMAGE` (and by default it will be called on `window`).

In `IMAGE`, your view model does not exist yet because you are using object notation.

You need to change the way you define your view model, from object to class and add the object in `IMAGETWO().base64StringArray();` as follows:

```
var CreateSalesVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.UserId = ko.observable();
    this.Name = ko.observable();
    this.Phone = ko.observable();
    this.Email = ko.observable();
    this.Item = ko.observable();
    this.Description = ko.observable();
    this.IMAGETWO = ko.observable({
        base64StringArray: ko.observableArray()
    });
    this.IMAGE = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.IMAGETWO().base64StringArray();
                 //^^^^ note this
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });
}
var myViewModel = new CreateSalesVM();
```

Comment: Hi this worked, however I could I know send this to the ajax data parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call *ko.toJSON()*, you'll get a copy of your VM serialized as *JSON*. In this case that you need to post your object using *ajax*, all you have to do is override the *toJSON()* function to remove the *IMAGETWO* property and add *IMAGE* property with the transformation (to base 64) needed.

```
var CreateSalesVM = {
    UserId: ko.observable(),
    Name: ko.observable(),
    Phone: ko.observable(),
    Email: ko.observable(),
    Item: ko.observable(),
    Description: ko.observable(),
    IMAGETWO: ko.observable({base64StringArray: ko.observableArray()})
}


CreateSalesVM.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var copy = ko.toJS(this); // clean copy
    copy.IMAGE = this.IMAGETWO().base64StringArray(); // create  desired property to send
    delete copy.IMAGETWO; //remove the undesired property
    return copy; //return the copy 
};
```

Check-out the original post [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html).